# how to calculate the cumulative sum of measure in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a date table and recon table. In recon table I have the measure of newly_reported_issue(new issues), measure of open issues and measure of closed issues and a column name recon_date(which will tell the date in which our issue occurred).
I created a Matrix in which i pass MonthName from date table in rows and in values i am passing newly_reported , issue_open and issue_closed. like this

```
MonthName   newly_reported   issue_open    issue_closed
January       6                   3             3
February      7                   4             3
March
```

now i want to calculate the cumulative sum of issue open so my expected output is like this

```
  MonthName   newly_reported     issue_closed    cumulative_open
    January       10                  7             3             
    February      12                  15            0
    March         14                  12            2
```

so the formula i am using is newly_reported - issue_closed + cumulative_open of previous one.

how to calculate this on powerbi?

Answer (score 0):

I created measure for calculating the cumulative open.

```
Cumulative_Open = IF(ISBLANK([Newly_Opened]) && ISBLANK([Total_Closed]), BLANK(), CALCULATE([Newly_Opened]-[Total_Closed],
FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date] <=  MAX('Date'[Date])
)))
```